# Polymer: is possible to add <content> inside a select (native or extended) tag?

Tags: polymer, html-select, polymer-1.0

I would to extend the native select tag functionalities (no, the "paper-dropdown-menu" component is not good for me).

I have a custom element with `<select>` tag and I call the element with `<options>` in its content.

This is an example of the element:

```
<dom-module id="my-select">
<template>
  <select id="select"
    disabled$="[[disabled]]"
    required$="[[required]]"
    autofocus$="[[autofocus]]"
    name$="[[name]]"
    size$="[[size]]"
    multiple$="[[multiple]]">
      <content></content>
  </select>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-select'
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

and I call the element with:

```
<my-select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</my-select>
```

In this way the select tag don't show any options (it doesn't add the content).

I've tried also extending the select tag:

```
<dom-module id="my-select">
<template>
  <select is="iron-select" id="select"
    disabled$="[[disabled]]"
    required$="[[required]]"
    autofocus$="[[autofocus]]"
    name$="[[name]]"
    size$="[[size]]"
    multiple$="[[multiple]]">
      <content></content>
  </select>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-select'
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

with "iron-select":

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'iron-select',
    extends: 'select'
  });
</script>
```

but it doesn't works too.

Did I forget something or this is a thing that is not possible to do (and I must create a brand new select component without the native select tag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot, or at least didn't show us the definitions of the properties that you bind to your select!
But the best option, like you mentioned is to extend a select:

```
<dom-module id="my-select">
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-select',
            extends: 'select'
            // add your stuff here...
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

and use it like this:

```
<select is="my-select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
<select>
```

With a working [JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/wuhiri/edit?html,output)

Comment: I don't use properties yet. My code could be rewritten as: `<select><content></content></select>` or, extending: `<select is="iron-select"><content></content></select>`. The problem is that I need to put unknown content for the "my-select" element. The "my-select" element should provide functionalities for the instances I will write and with unknown content to the "my-select" element.  Chrome don't render the content I've provided externally the "my-select", so I guess that the <content> doesn't works inside a native element.